# Intercepting the Fn key on laptops

Tags: language-agnostic, keyboard, hook, keyboard-hook

Sometimes when I work on Thinkpads/MSI laptops, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> key are swapped (<kbd>Fn</kbd> being the leftmost key), and it drives me nuts - I keep hitting <kbd>Fn</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

I was wondering if it's at all possible to intercept the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key. I'd like to write a hook that swaps the  <kbd>Ctrl / Fn</kbd>  keys, but it seems that <kbd>Fn</kbd> is not being processed by the OS at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry. As you mentioned, the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key isn't processed by the OS, but received as tuples of  <kbd>Fn + [key]</kbd> . The best you could probably do would be mapping every <kbd>Fn + [key]</kbd>   combination to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> (and that's only if you never use <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys).

Edit: Found [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys). Before you give up hope, might want to give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. I tried AutoHotkey before, and unfortunately it didn't recognize the Fn combinations on my HP laptop. I'll try it later on some Thinkpads.

Comment: Deep in a wall of text it mentions that, for some IBM models, switching fn and ctrl is a BIOS option away.

Comment: Mike - On a ThinkPad W500 w/ Windows 7 Home Premium (64 bit) and running Key Tweak, pressing the Fn key (alone) registers with a scan code.  Does this imply the key is indeed processed by the OS?

Comment: Matt - Yes, so you should be able to remap it.

Answer (score 6):

As stated above the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key generally operates on a lower level than the OS and hence modifying its behaviour Generally this depends on the manufacturer. Some manufacturers who are not jerks generally provide an option (typically in BIOS) which will allow swapping <kbd>Fn - Ctrl</kbd>  keys. I have also heard of people taking the extreme option of physically modifying their keyboards (opening them up and rerouting the circuits in the wafer) to swap the <kbd>Fn - Ctrl</kbd> keys.

Thinkpad specific: Lenovo included a bios option for their Tx10 (or Tx20? not sure) and above series laptops for <kbd>Fn - Ctrl</kbd> switch.

For older models, a user called middleton on forums.notebookreview.com has posted a series of modified BIOS's for lenovo laptops that swap the <kbd>Fn  - Ctrl</kbd>. It should go without mentioning that as these are completely off-reservation they are to be used at ones own risk.

http://forum.notebookreview.com/lenovo-ibm/474396-fn-ctrl-swap-all-lenovo-laptops-solved.html

If I ever make a lot of money I will contract out hitmen to track down and execute those responsible for going against such well established standards.

Answer (score 1):

On my HP laptop, for whatever reason, the designers decided to put a column of the quick-function media keys. So, at the bottom most-left corner of my keyboard is a calculator key, rather than the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.

I found a piece of software called [KeyTweak](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/) that I use to remap the calculator key to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.