# Reading "Fn" key

Tags: python, keyboard

I'd like to find out the easiest way how to read <kbd>Fn</kbd> key from my keyboard in Python (Windows).I've tried to use [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org) library, but it didn't work for <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intercepting the Fn key on laptops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514781/intercepting-the-fn-key-on-laptops)

Comment: Tkinter can catch function keys.  See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Where's the bit on that page that says Fn can be caught by Tkinter? Note that this is `"Fn"`, not `"F"+n`.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal:  My mistake. +1 on on your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Fn" key is usually a proprietary, device-specific modifier that is handled by the device driver (or the hardware itself). It's not a normal button, and you can't catch it in your code. To be honest, I can't imagine why you'd ever possibly want to.

Comment: Usually it is handled by hardware, though on some keyboards pressing it alone generates scancode too

Comment: If it generates a scancode, Pygame should be able to process it. The value of the scancode would depend on hardware anyway, though.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I'd like to create program with my own shortcuts usable in Windows.

Comment: @Stanyko: Create your own brand of keyboard then. Fn is not for you.