# How to determine the laptops FN keyboard button HEX code?

Tags: python, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, scancodes

I have a python script which presses <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> and so on to control the special brightness/volume functions.

I do not know the HEX code for the <kbd>FN</kbd> button. I tried 255 but it does not seem to be ok.

I've tried to determine it with KeyView.exe. It provides the HEX code for the pressed keys. For RightArrow it has a small value and for <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>RightArrow</kbd> it has a bigger one. I substract them and find <kbd>FN</kbd> value (174 or something like that). But it does not work this way neither.

I've looked on a bunch of websites and installed several additional tools, but I can't figure it out. Could I maybe lower my brightness automatically in some other ways?

The laptop is a Lenovo Y50-70 and I run Windows 10.

Any ideas, guys?
Thank you!

Comment: Which laptop is this?

Comment: I've updated my post. Thank you!

Comment: fn keys usually don't have scan codes. They are processed at a much lower level.

Comment: Look at this: https://superuser.com/a/525660/258068

Comment: @HaveSpacesuit - It really worked!
Thank you very much for the link! It is an alternative solution, but it solves my actual problem. :) GJ!

Answer (score 1):

Try [showkey](https://linux.die.net/man/1/showkey), e.g.

```
$ sudo showkey -k
```

This will dump any key press to stdout.

Comment: I forgot to mention. I run Windows 10 on my laptop. No sudo for me. :(

Comment: you could check this then : https://superuser.com/questions/189065/key-code-checker-for-windows

Comment: Thank you, Loic. FN+Right (for brightness) does not throw a result unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 0):

The `Fn` key does not have a scan code. Send a [virtual key](https://jacksautohotkeyblog.wordpress.com/2016/04/29/when-to-use-virtual-keys-and-keyboard-scan-codes-with-autohotkey-beginning-hotkeys-part-14/) instead.

Comment: That might work for the volume controls, but there's no virtual-key for the brightness ones

Comment: Exactly my case. :( Is there any other way than simulating key press to send a lower brightness command?

Comment: @bvg Post it as a separate question

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of many other questions such as [Reading "Fn" key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713539/reading-fn-key) and [Intercepting the Fn key on laptops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514781/intercepting-the-fn-key-on-laptops) (I don't have enough reputation to mark it so).

TLDR: In at least most cases it's impossible, it's a functionality handled internally by the laptop and not manageable from the operating system

Comment: I've checked them out before, of course, but they were asked 6 and 8 years ago. Things changed since then, isn't it? :(

Comment: @bvg So you duplicated a question knowingly without even referencing the old ones you already checked?

Comment: @bvg Things haven't changed, by the way. And for the brightness functions, it's very likely that even the (potential) models that do send scan codes most likely intend them as notifications _after the fact_ , and sending them from an application would have no effect on the brightness (if it weren't so the brightness controls would not work outside operating systems that support them).