# How to hook notebook's hardware keys?

Tags: c#, keyboard, hook, pinvoke, device-driver

I've got an [Acer Aspire 5740G](http://support.acer.com/product/default.aspx?modelId=1870) and I want to intercept the hardware buttons. I wrote a C# application using `SetWindowsHookEx()`.

For the volume buttons, for example, I receive `VolumeUp` and `VolumeDown` messages, all are fine. But for the **wifi button** and **bluetooth button**, I only receive `LBUTTON`, `OEMCLEAR`(KeyCode 255). So how can I differentiate between **those two**?

I've also read, that this, buttons may inaccessible because they would be treated like *Fn-Keys* which are below the OS. But there's an Acer software, called [Launch Manager](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Application/LaunchManager/LaunchManager_Dritek_3.0.04_W7x86W7x64_A.zip?acerid=633965387932449137&Step1=NOTEBOOK,%20ULTRABOOK&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%205740&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_7), which shows OSD messages and show a bluetooth/wifi logo. So it must be possible(at least in theory) to differentiate these buttons at the OS level.

So, how to hook these keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a related question

- [Intercepting the Fn key on laptops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514781/intercepting-the-fn-key-on-laptops)

Don't know if you ever wrote Windows drivers.

Windows drivers, well, it's a long history.

Modern Windows has two mode of device drivers:

- kernel mode driver, see [Kernel-Mode Driver Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-Mode_Driver_Framework)
- user mode driver see [Windows User Mode Driver Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-Mode_Driver_Framework)

Since you've found that those two buttons have identical windows message, it is possibly controled by the kernel mode drivers.

Some hardware singals might not have a `WM_` messages definition, sometimes they simply mapping to one identical windows message, but the kernel mode driver can distinguish them. There are tons of, for example, `Ke` bla bla and `IRP_` bla bla stuffs; some even can only wrote in C/C++, that is, native code; and you would possibly have no way except look into the driver.

If you are really interested in Windows drivers, take a look of [Windows Driver Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557573.aspx), and WDK(Windows Driver Kit) is free for download.

Finally, if you **STRONGLY** want the technical support from the manufacturer(Acer), leave a comment to let me know if we shall get in contact and I'll reply with my email.

Comment: This answer is for a direction of your question, but it's too long to put in a comment. I'm considering to delete it later.

Comment: At first - thank you for your answer. Second - please don't delete it. I think it may help other users who face the same problem. ;)